# Convolutional neural network with grayscale images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a CNN (convolutional neural network) with 1 channel/grayscale images with size 28x28 pixels. When I try to train the model it says:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 28, 28]

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(28, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(56, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(56, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(56, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(62))

model.summary()
```

Comment: maybe change your inptu_shape to four dim with 1,1,28,28?

Comment: @SirBaum input_shape adds the batch dimension by itself I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to submit images in the format that supports channel's dimension, i.e. your image has to have shape of (28, 28, 1) - three dimensions, not two.
In general the input is four dimensional: (batch_size, width, height, num_of_channels).
You didn't provide the code, which you use for training, so I can't be more specific with how to fix the problem with your input dataset shape.

Comment: For training my model, the code I used was 
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))

Comment: how do you init **train_images** and **test_images**?
If they are numpy arrays then just reshape them to have one additional dimension of size 1 at the end

Comment: How would I add a dimension of size 1 to a numpy array?

Comment: `myarray[..., None]`

Comment: The model is able to train now, but right before it finishes training an error comes up with the message
" Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 28, 28] "

Comment: x = x.reshape(x.shape + (1,))
or
x = x[..., np.newaxis]

Comment: @YuriKreinin I changed both my training and testing images to the required shape (28, 28, 1) (excluding batch size), however after the model finishes training it still says the same error 
"Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 28, 28]"

Comment: Please, provide the entire code example, including **model.compile** and **model.fit**,
use np.random for datset and labels. I will check it on my machine, if you provide the full code. **Please, do it with np.random simulated datasets**

Comment: Sorry I realized I forgot a line of code I thought I had written already. Thank you for all the help @YuriKreinin !